# What is the closest point to $(0,-1/2)$ on the curve $x^2+2y=0$? Why can't I differentiate over $y$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Let $L$ be the distance between $(x,y)$ on the curve $x^2+2y=0$ and $(0,-1/2)$.
Then $L^2=x^2+(y+\frac{1}{2})^2=-2y+(y+\frac{1}{2})^2$,
$\frac{dL^2}{dy}=-2+2(y+\frac{1}{2})=0$,
which gives $y=1/2$.

But this is clearly incorrect. $y=1/2$ does not even lie on the curve!

I know that if we express $y$ in terms of $x$, and then differentiate over $x$, we can get the correct answer $(0,0)$.

But I don't figure out what's wrong when we differentiate over $y$.

Comment: All the given answers are missing a picture. This problem needs a picture.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook In my answer I suggested the OP draw one.

Comment: This problem does not really need a picture and can be solved conventionally with single-variable calculus methods.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yes it can be so solved. But the OP wanted some intuition about why what s/he thought was a routine application of single-variable calculus didn't work. A picture can provide that intuition. And when you encounter problems that don't necessarily have routine solutions, you want to begin with intuition to suggest a solution. There's a lot to learn from this question.

Comment: @EthanBolker Intuition need not be visual/geometric, although I will concede that usually this is simpler. For this particular case, the observation that $y=-x^2/2$ shows that $y\leq 0$ without having to resort to visuals, which aren't always available in any case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting puzzle.

If you draw a picture you'll see the problem. Both the picture and the algebra tell you that $y$ must be nonpositive.

Now think more carefully about how you find the minimum of a differentiable function. That can occur at a root of the derivative *or at an end point of the domain*.

In this case the minumum is at $0$; the distance increases as $|y|$ increases along the negative $y$-axis.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a minimization problem of the quadratic function $x^2+(y+\frac12)^2$ under the quadratic constraint $x^2+2y=0$.

As $y$ is constrained (it must be non-positive), nothing guarantees that the minimum occurs at a stationary point, it can occur at the endpoint $y=0$ instead.

On the opposite, $x$ is unconstrained.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have [Ethan Bolker's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2721879/123905).  I'm going to ask you a question that might make it clearer.  Let $f$ have domain $(-1,3]$ and be given by $f(x) = x^2$ on that domain.  Where is the maximum of $f$?  (It's not where the derivative is zero; that's the global minimum.)  Could we have gotten a bigger maximum if (somehow) we could expand the domain a little?  Does this mean, in addition to points where the derivative is zero, we must check points where the derivative is undefined (for instance, where we cannot take limits from both sides)?

Comment: The derivative is not undefined at endpoints. In particular $dL^2/dy=-1$ at $y=0$ here.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : "The derivative" requires a two-sided limit.  You can make a one-sided variant of the derivative (and people do), but it is not "the derivative".

Comment: Quite embarrassingly, I have actually learnt the concept of global max/min. In this case, I failed to realize the implicit constraint on y. Anyway, thanks for your inverse teaching method.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Again, I agree that there *exist* one-sided limits and have already said as much.  "The derivative" is not defined using one-sided limits in a class where "calculus" is an appropriate tag.  These would be the analog of directional derivatives applied to the single variable case and would require explicitly specifying a direction.  ... or are you claiming the absolute value function is differentiable everywhere?

Comment: @YvesDaoust : At your link, I see "$f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dots$", which is neither "$f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \dots$" nor "$f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \dots$", so is a two-sided limit.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : You might benefit from reading http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Limit.html , where the notations for indicating direction of these limits is displayed.  Note the phrase 'if the two are equal, then "the" limit is said to exist'.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : You fell in the trap.  The limit outside the domain is undefined because the difference quotient is.  Therefore it cannot be equal because it has no value.

Comment: @EricTowers: review the definition of a limit.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : 'if the two are equal, then "the" limit is said to exist'.  If they don't agree or if at least one is undefined, "the" limit does not exist.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Also, nothing in the $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition there requires that points from the topological space must come from the domain of the function.  It is quite clear that in OP's setting, the topological space extends substantially past the domain.  Consequently, a point on the boundary of the domain which is an accumulation point of the ambient topological space cannot support a derivative because the difference quotient fails to exist beyond the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Minimize $L^2=x^2+\left(y+\frac12\right)^2$ subject to $x^2+2y=0$.

The constrained optimization problem can be solved by the method of substitution. Substituting $y=-\frac{x^2}{2}$ works smoothly as OP stated.

Substituting $x^2=-2y$ has additional implicit constraints on $x$ and $y$:
$$y=-\frac{x^2}{2} \Rightarrow x\in (-\infty,+\infty); y\in (-\infty,0].$$

So after substitution $x^2=-2y$, we get another constrained optimization problem:
$$\text{Min} L^2=-2y+\left(y+\frac12\right)^2 \ \text{s.t.} \ \ y\in (-\infty,0].$$

According to Extreme value theorem, the optimum occurs either at critical (provided it belongs to feasible region) or border points. The critical point $y=\frac12$ does not belong to $(-\infty,0]$. Hence the minimum is at the border $y=0$. Note that $L^2(-\infty)=+\infty$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

Pedestrian approach:

1) $y=-(1/2)x^2$ is a parabola, $Y-$axis is symmetry axis, vertex $(0,0)$, opening downward.

2) Point $P (0,-1/2)$.

Restrict calculation to 3rd quadrant, symmetry, i.e.

$x\ge 0$, $y \le 0$.

3) We are looking for a point $(x,y)$ on the parabola that has minimal distance to $P$.

4)$D(y)=  -2y +(y+1/2)^2$, where $D(y)= (distance)^2$.

Recall $y \le 0$:

$D'(y) = -2 +2(y+1/2) =$

$ -1 +2y \lt 0$.

Hence $D'(y)$ is a strictly decreasing function.

The maximum is at $y=0$.

$D(y=0)= 1/4$.

Formally:  $D'(y) =0$ , gives $y = 1/2$,

but this value is ruled out since we consider the 3rd quadrant , where $x\ge0, y\le 0$.

Note: The function $D(y)$ , $y \in R$,  has a minimum at $y=1/2$, which is $D(y=1/2)=0$.